# How to print a part of a vector of unsigned chars properly?

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
std::vector<BYTE> bytes = readFile(path.c_str());
```

Lets say i want to print from position 30 to 34 in the vector.

i tried this:

```
unsigned char chars[4];
for (int i = 30; i < 34; i++)
{
    chars[i-30] = bytes[i];
}

std::cout << chars << std::endl;
```

I get a weird symbol and thats all.
The vector of chars from 30 to 34 contains \x14, \0 \0 \0.
I tried casting the chars to unsigned int, and some similar stuff.

Comment: Question is what have you read from file and why do you expect it is printable?

Comment: First you have to decide what you mean by "properly". Do you mean decimal values? Characters (according to which encoding)? What?

Comment: Well we are expected to load and use the data, so i guess the data can be read and be used normally.

e.g. loading this sequence of characters: \x14, \0 \0 \0 which is:
20 nothing nothing nothing, im supposed to store it in a int as 20.


By properly means, that it works. Sorry for confusing words.

Answer (score 0):

If you just write `std::cout << chars << std::endl`, of course it's going to print weird things since chars is a pointer. It prints the value at its address and at the following locations until the value it reaches reads `\0`. Make a loop over your `chars` array to print its content instead of trying to print it directly. Also cast as an int if you want the output formatted correctly:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    std::cout << static_cast<unsigned int>(chars[i]) << std::flush;
}
```

Comment: Yea, that works partly, because it prints the \0 as zero's.
Any way to bypass that ? The \0 arent supposed to get printed.

Comment: Using conditions:  
`if (chars[i] != 0) { /*print your non-0 char here*/ }`

Answer (score 0):

You could use this as well (and yes it skips the `'\0'`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

typedef unsigned char BYTE;
struct printer{
    void operator()(BYTE c){
        if(c != 0){
            cout << c;
        }
    }
} printer;

int main() {

    vector<BYTE> v ={'a', '\0' ,'b', '\0', 'c', 'D'};
    BYTE a[6] = {'h', '\0', 'i', '\0', 'o', 'p'};
    for_each (v.begin(), v.end(), printer);
    cout<<endl <<"Now array" << endl;
    for_each (a, a + 6, printer);
    return 0;
}
```

[On ideone](http://ideone.com/Xq64nc) as well...